# Is there a way to automatically declare external exports for Javascript / Typescript module?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this one typescript library being shared with all other projects. Sort of like a commons library. The "main" configured inside the package.json is the index.js. I find myself manually importing and then exporting all the individual modules from this project's source into the main index.js. Is there a better way to export them all much like how public classes are all exposed in Java?

Comment: External modules are external and they're not a part of javascript's functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. All ECMAScript modules (which TypeScript compiles to) must explicitly `export` any object they wish to `import` elsewhere. Nothing can be implicitly exported or imported.